# What can you observe from MRI noises?

Tags: mri, procedural-behavior, procedural-expectations

While in an MRI you hear a lot of different noises. The pitch changes, as does the pattern and rhythm. Sometimes there's one long noise, sometimes a beep-beep-beep then a pause and the same set of beeps again, and so on. At times a pattern repeats without change for many minutes, while at other times the noises vary more frequently. CBC Spark had [an item](http://www.cbc.ca/radio/spark/289-music-and-tech-week-1.3109376/video-i-hear-music-in-the-mri-1.4124448) comparing it to electronic music.

What do these noises tell you? And what about the pauses between them? Is it, for example, safe to move a tiny bit if there is no noise? I sometimes find that I have tensed up and lifted a leg off the surface a tiny bit and I want to relax and put it back down. Is doing that in a silent part better than doing that during noises?

I'm just curious I suppose, but knowledge is always reassuring. Just like understanding the bell noises on an airplane, I want to understand the MRI noises.

Answer (score 4):

[TLDR:  The gradient coils.]

That is a great question.  There are three parts to an [MRI machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_magnetic_resonance_imaging):  main magnetic field (1.5 Tesla, 3 Tesla etc), gradient coil system and radio-frequency coil.

The main magnetic field is static, meaning is doesn't change.  Once the technician has "ramped up" the scanner, it will not change. It doesn't get shut down at all.  So, this part of the system is quiet.

The radio frequency (RF) coil is typically what is *placed* on or around the person's head, shoulder, knee etc.  The RF coil both sends radio frequencies into the body and receives radio frequencies from the body. This is the way data is "read" from an MRI scanner.  The RF coil is quiet too.

The [gradient coils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_magnetic_resonance_imaging#Gradients) are a separate set of coils inside the scanner shrouding (so you don't see them) that are (typically) cylindrical in shape, so the MRI bed is basically sliding you inside them.  The magnetic field gradient coils have electrical impulses put through them at a very, very fast rate (millisecond range). So, [the electricity going through them at such a high rate produces mechanical torque](https://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/17/science/why-mri-machines-make-that-loud-noise.html) (meaning the coils actual twist slightly) and that is what you are hearing.  NOW, with all that being said, they are manufactured with very strict safety constraints etc so the torquing is not something to be worried about.   :)

Most scans are acquired as "lines" of data and each line of data is typically one quick set of noises you hear.  [The line of [data is acquired in "Fourier space"](https://mriquestions.com/fourier-transform-ft.html) which is the Fourier transform of image space.] Any movement even during the quiet periods can or will typically produce [artifacts in the images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRI_artifact#Motion_artifacts). So it is best to stay as still as comfortably possible during the scan.

[Update]

Further good questions... So, a typical MRI scan (20-40 minute session) consists of, typically 3-5 scans.  [Each scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging#Sequences) has different parameters in order to create images with different contrast. Each manufacturer might have a slightly different procedure but here is typically how things work...

Given one of the scans there are typically two parts to it.

The first part, which lasts 10s of seconds, or so, is a tuning part. And, **this** consists of a few parts.  So, the first tuning part of the sequence determines how much radio frequency (RF) power needs to be used to get some pre-determined affect (usually a 90 degree pulse). This will sound like just a few clicks spaced apart by ~1s.  Once the RF power is determined, then it uses that information and runs a very short part of the MRI scan to make sure the data coming back is decent (in very general terms).

Once all this tuning stuff is done, then the **actual** MRI scan runs. This is the part that will run for a few minutes to many minutes (typically).  The main part of the MRI scan typically has a very short RF pulse played out, then the gradient coil plays (to do spatial encoding) and then there is a delay.  This whole thing is repeated many times to acquire all the data.  The delay can be very short (milliseconds) or very long (~seconds).  The time from when the RF pulse is played out to the end of the delay is the TR time (repetition time). There is a decent description of the relationship of all these things [here](https://www.imaios.com/en/e-Courses/e-MRI/MRI-signal-contrast/Signal-weighting).

So, for the actual scan:

```
   RF pulse -- Gradients ---- delay 

   ^------------- TR -------------^
```

And this block is repeated.

To go even one more step further, one can add some RF and gradient stuff *before* each RF pulse (above) as a way of creating even different contrast than normal in the images.  That is a whole different topic.

For example, a typical brain scan for multiple sclerosis might consist of:

1. Dual echo spin echo, this one will have a relatively long delay for each TR interval (~second or so).
2. T1-weighted scan, this one will have a relatively short delay for each TR interval (~50-100 milliseconds or so).

Oh, and one other thing. For the most part, MRI scans are not "adapative" in the sense that *usually* they don't acquire a bit of data and then check to see if it is good, and then decide to keep it or not.  Most scans these days are done and then the MRI technician will check to see if the whole thing needs to be repeated. Some scans can kind of do adaptive scanning but I think that technology on a hospital scanner is still being develped and something to come in the future.

There are so many interesting things here, and so many more details. I have to admit, I really enjoy MRI.

Comment: Welcome to SciMed.SE. Great answer! But in order to comply with site requirements could you please edit it and add at least one reference supporting your answer?

Comment: Given the general knowledge for this, I hope Wikipedia is acceptable.  :)

Comment: it is interesting to know which bit makes the noise, and why, but I was thinking more at a meta level. Say I hear beep boop beep boop 20 times, then a pause. Then bikbikbikbik over and over. Did the first sound represent a try that wasn't good? If the bikbikbik last like 5 minutes, are they getting great images? Why does it sometimes last 10 minutes? (Once, I was convinced it was some sort of unattended alarm and my tech had actually left. It was not :-) ) Why are the quiet periods sometimes very long? These are the things you think while you can't do anything else for 45 minutes.